# How to dismis custom dialog from a custom button in dialog?

Tags: android, dialog, dismiss

```
Hi there,

    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        inviteView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.invite_dialog, null);
        builder.setView(inviteView);
        sendSmsButton = (Button) inviteView.findViewById(R.id.sendSMSButton);
        sendEmailButton = (Button) inviteView.findViewById(R.id.sendEmailButton);


        builder.setTitle(R.string.invite_callrz_title);
        sendSmsButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

        sendEmailButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancelItem,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
        return builder.create();
    }
```

I have a custom layout with 2 buttons on it.I also use a default nagativeButton to dismis the dialog. My question is I would like to dismis the dialog bar when the custom buttons are clicked. Basically, when the button is clicked, it will do some staff and dismis the dialog. which method I should call?

Comment: what happens if you put      dialog.cancel();
 in sendEmailButton or  sendSmsButton's click method?

Comment: i tried that one didnt work. because it complains that hasnt got DialogInterface. But I got it worked. basically I can call dismissDialog(int id); from activity to dismiss the dialog bar.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
AlertDialog alertDialog; 
alertDialog = builder.create();

sendSmsButton = (Button) builder.findViewById(R.id.sendSMSButton);

sendSmsButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            alertDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
```