# Android "Dialog" instace is "null" when tried to "dismiss"

Tags: android, dialog, adapter

I have a custom dialog created inside an Adapter, which has two buttons ((+)ve and (-)ve), (+)ve vl call another service and (-)ve will simply dismiss the dialog.

```
public class BookingAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<BookingItem> {

    private Dialog aDialog;
    private Context context;
    private Activity activity;

    public BookingAdapter (Context context, int resource, List<BookingItem> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        this.context = context;
        this.activity = (Activity) context;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        // some other tasks being done
        onButtonClick(position, holder);
        return convertView;
    }

    public void onButtonClick(final int position, ViewHolder viewHolder){

        // some other tasks being done
        makeDialog(name, id, date, cost);
    }

    public void makeDialog(final String name, final String Id, final String date, String cost){

        Button confirmButton;
        Button cancelAndReturnButton;
        TextView confirmDialogBody;

        aDialog = new Dialog(activity, R.style.Dialog_No_Border);
        aDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        LayoutInflater m_inflater = LayoutInflater.from(activity);
        View m_view = m_inflater.inflate(R.layout.casual_day_booking_confirm_dialog, null);

        // set Buttons and Texts

        View.OnClickListener m_clickListener = new View.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View p_v) {

                switch (p_v.getId()) {

                    case R.id.confirm_and_proceed:                        
                        PlaceBookingTask bookingTask = new PlaceBookingTask(date,Id,context);
                        bookingTask.execute();
                        break;
                    case R.id.cancel_and_return:
                        aDialog.dismiss();
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        };
        aDialog.setContentView(m_view);
        if(!activity.isFinishing()) {

            aDialog.show();
        }
    }

    @Subscribe
    public void onSuccess(PlaceBookingEvent event){

        PlaceBookingResponse response = event.getPlaceBookingResponse();
        aDialog.dismiss();
        secondConfirmationDialog(response.getName, response.getDate, response.getId);
    }

    public void secondConfirmationDialog(String name,String date,String id) {
        // this will create another dialog
    }
}
```

When onSuccess, `aDialog.dismiss()`, aDialog is `null` and cannot be dismissed.

i checked some similar  questions in SO like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8091858/how-to-dismis-custom-dialog-from-a-custom-button-in-dialog) and [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_alert_dialoges.htm), i'm doubt that only `AlertDialog.Builder` is the solution for my problem.

Comment: check `if(dialog!=null && dialog.isShowing())` then `dismiss`

Comment: @MD you are right but it won't help to close the dialog.

Comment: i do not understand. What is the problem actually???

Comment: the dialog need to be dismissed. But even though it opened its showing `aDialog` is null

Comment: Yess but when? Without opening you want close? howz that's possible??

Comment: inside `makeDialog` method dialog opened, i want to close it inside `onSuccess` method.

Comment: where is makeDialog method being called?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the "private" in your variable.

Comment: Is that really an answer??

Comment: @Detilium its not helpfull,. can you justify ??

Answer (score 0):

I think your dialog implementation is wrong. Try with the following.

```
        // custom dialog
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom);
        dialog.setTitle("Title...");

        // set the custom dialog components - text, image and button
        TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.text);
        text.setText("Android custom dialog example!");
        ImageView image = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.image);
        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

        Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogButtonOK);
        // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
        dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        dialog.show();
```